# This error keeps occurring in haskell any idea on how to fix it?

Tags: haskell

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
step :: (Num a, Read a) => String -> a
step = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words
where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
        foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
        foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "/" = (x / y):ys
        foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
        foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

The code above keeps giving this error: I have tried to fix it by changing step to solveRPN and tried taking out the square brackets [], but i keep getting this error.

```
haskell.hs:4:1: error: parse error on input ‘where’
  |
4 | where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
  | ^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

1. Do not use two type signatures for a single function.  You have `step :: ...` twice, pick one signatures and delete the other.
2. `where` must be indented.
3. Your function isn't type-correct so you'll still have things to work through.